# visual studio header

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm a newbie to visual studio. I am following a tutorial to learn C++ and they have provided some headers for the course. So when i work with projects i include the headers in the header folder of the solution explorer on the left. But when i run the program, i get errors that the headers are no where to be found. pls help.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please provide more details.  Exactly how are you adding the header files?  Could you post your source code?

Comment: Well i jus open a new project. On the project solution explorer, i right click on the header folder and add existing item. I browse for the header and select it. Then in my main cpp file i make the header declarations.

Comment: @Jay You're using `#include "headername.h"`, right?  Not `#include <headername.h>`?

Comment: hmmm come to think of it, i never knew there was a difference in those two usage. I use the conventional one <headername.h>

Comment: but then when i used the project files they gave me, there the header was declared as "headername.h". Still it dint work .

Comment: In short `"headername"` searches (relative to) the current directory first, then all include directories specified in the compiler options. `<headername>` skips the current directory.

Comment: Please provide the location of someof the .cpp / .h files in trouble, the include statement(s), and your Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/VC++ Directories settings for include files.

Answer (score 3):

Use menu Tools, Options, Projects and Solutions, VC++ Directories to set the path where VS will seach the headers.